# Angular 2: how to bind a subcomponent to property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

How can I bind subcomponent mainmenu in template to property menu?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { MainMenuComponent } from './main-menu.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="centered">
      <mainmenu></mainmenu>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  menu: MainMenuComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#parent-calls-a-viewchild-) annotation:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(MainMenuComponent) menu: MainMenuComponent;
}
```